# How to deploy machine learning model saved as pickle file on AWS SageMaker

Tags: machine-learning, deployment, amazon-sagemaker

I have built an XGBoost Classifier and RandomForest Classifier model for the audio classification project. I want to deploy these models which are saved in pickle (.pkl) format on AWS Sagemaker. From what I have observed, there isn't a lot of resources available online. Can anyone guide me with the steps and if possible also provide the code? I already have the models built and I'm just left with deploying it on Sagemaker.

Answer (score 1):

By saying that you want to deploy to sagemaker, I assume you mean a sagemaker endpoint.

The answer is sagemaker inference toolkit. It's basically about educating sagemaker how to load and do inference. More details here: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-inference-toolkit and here is an example implementation: https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/multi_model_bring_your_own